# System call interruption

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, signals

I have a problem to solve: some thread in my process is performing a synchronous system call, which I want to interrupt immediately. To solve this problem I can send a signal by `pthread_kill`, which should force it return with `EINTR`. I made a snippet of code to illustrate this:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SIG SIGALRM

int work = 1;

void signal_action(int signal)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s caught\n", strsignal(signal));
}

void* thread_routine(void* arg)
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = signal_action;

    if(sigaction(SIG, &sa, NULL) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "sigaction failed with %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        return NULL;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Thread working\n");
    while(work)
    {
        int rc = select(0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if(rc < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Select error: %d (%s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Select return %d\n", rc);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pthread_t handle;
    int rc = pthread_create(&handle, NULL, thread_routine, NULL);
    if(rc != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create failed with %d (%s)\n", rc, strerror(rc));
        return 1;
    }

    sleep(1);

    work = 0;
    rc = pthread_kill(handle, SIG);
    if(rc != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_kill failed with %d (%s)\n", rc, strerror(rc));
        return 1;
    }

    rc = pthread_join(handle, NULL);
    if(rc != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "pthread_join failed with %d (%s)\n", rc, strerror(rc));
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But it makes me to define a dummy function (signal_action), as it is not working another way. So, 2 questions:

- Is there another option for interrupting a system call in another thread?
- Is there a way to avoid using dummy constructions in the method shown above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use other synchronisation mechanismes between threads, but as you want to interrupt a blocking system call, I cannot imagine something different than a `pthread_kill`.

And you need to use an explicit `signal_action` because the defaults would be either to completely ignore the signal (and you do not want that), or to abort the whole program (and you do not want that either). So no, I cannot imagine a way to avoid the explicit `signal_action`.